# Using the keyword self on a child class to call one superclass method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

**It works now, the problem was with Xcode.It was solved by restarting Xcode and trying a clean build, thanks for trying!**

**Parent Class**

**CardGame.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Deck.h"

@interface CardGame : NSObject

- (id) initWithCardCount:(NSUInteger)cardCount usingDeck:(Deck *) deck;

- (Card *) cardAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;

@end
```

**Child Class**

**CardMatchingGame.h**

```
#import "CardGame.h"

@interface CardMatchingGame : CardGame

- (void) flipCardAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;

@end
```

**CardMatchingGame.m**

```
- (void) flipCardAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index {
Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index]; // The error I get is on this line
self.currentAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You flipped up %@", 
                                                        card.contents];
```

**The error I get**

No visible @interface for 'CardMatchingGame' declares the selector cardAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;

I have browsed through similar questions but the answer has to do with the child class not finding the correct parent file, this is not the case for me. I'm a novice in inheritance, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Where do you call the `initWithCardCount:usingDeck:` method from? Does the class import `CardMatchingGame.h`? Does `CardMatchingGame.h` import `CardGame.h`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I posted the error wrong, see the edit.

Comment: But does `CardMatchingGame.m` import `CardMatchingGame.h` or `CardGame.h`?

Comment: It imports CardMatchingGame.h which does import CardGame.h.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode gets confused when editing files. Restart Xcode, reopen the project. Do a clean build if that doesn't work.

Comment: Glad it worked. Actually I just remembered an easier fix when run into this again. Just edit the line a little. For example, delete one letter from the method call, then put back the letter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import CardGame.h. If you don't import it, the complier complains that it can't find it, since you don't refer to it in your subclass code.

Example: type `import "CardGame.h"` at the top of CardMatchingGame.h

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type that in the questions, I actually imported that.

Comment: `@interface CardMatchingGame : CardGame` this is wrong, it should inherit from `NSObject` not `CardGame`

Comment: You need to import Deck.h in CardMatchingGame.h, not CardGame.h

Comment: @edwardmp Your last comments are incorrect. `CardMatchingGame` extends `CardGame`. And the imports are correct (at least as shown in the question).

Comment: I recognized this from a Stanford tutorial, I checked it and it doesn't match his code in those parts.

Comment: Its fixed now, but it is part of my solution to assignment 2, I'm making a superclass CardGame so the Card Matching Game and Set can extend it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your implementation of `cardAtIndex:` - you are making some mistake in that code. My guess is that you might be calling `initWithCardCount:` the wrong way - perhaps as a class method when in fact it is an instance method.

Comment: But it would help if you actually showed that code, since that seems to be where the problem is.